# Help I burn my mango tree

Tags: fruit-trees

[image]
**strong text**

Help me please i accidentally burn my mango tree

Comment: Hi there, where is the plant located and how did it get burned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing you can do about it other than to remove severely burned parts.  It should recover over time, since some of the tree seems untouched by fire.